# How to convert prepared statement into String

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to set a string value into DB using prepared statement and Result Set. But it inserts into DB row this "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@fcd6521"

```
PreparedStatement check = connection.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT buildingName FROM building GROUP BY buildingId HAVING buildingId = ?");
check.setInt(1, building_id);
ResultSet rs = check.executeQuery();
insert.setString(1, String.valueOf(rs));
insert.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Tutorial from Oracle [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)

Comment: What do you expect to get from `String.valueOf(rs)`? It will not give you the data.

Comment: Aside from that, I would use a single SQL statement if possible: `INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES ( (SELECT buildingName FROM building GROUP BY buildingId HAVING buildingId = ?)...)`

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need to read the tutorial indicated by @user16320675
A ResultSet is a type of set. It has to be accessed like that:

```
//if you expects receive only one buildName you use a simple if, otherwise you have to use a loop and a list or something like that
String text;
if(rs.next()){
    text = rs.getString(0);
}
//index it's related to buildingName
```